# Adding effect to scrollTo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, scrollto

here is slider code -

```
function scrollToRight() {
    if (global_current_elem == 5) {elem = 1;}
    else {elem = global_current_elem + 1;}
    jQuery('#slider_element').scrollTo('#element'+elem, 500, {easing:'easeInOutCubic', axis:'x' });
    set_active_btn(elem);
    global_current_elem = elem;
}

function scrollToLeft() {
    if (global_current_elem == 1) {elem = 5;}
    else {elem = global_current_elem - 1;}
    jQuery('#slider_element').scrollTo('#element'+elem, 500, {easing:'easeInOutCubic', axis:'x' });
    set_active_btn(elem);
    global_current_elem = elem; 
}
```

Is there any chance of adding to it sexy slider effects when new slide comes (fading, cubic changing e.c.), like on this slider - http://lastcover.devilcantburn.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery UI to add effects.

sample code

```
$( "#effect" ).effect( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
```

docs on using effects

http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but how to integrate it into slideTo?

Comment: Don't use slideTo. Make the objects that aren't being viewed invisible and use the effect you want to display them.

Comment: on a side note.
This is where to get the slider you linked to if you want to use it.
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/